First Collection view autoscroll, scroll other collection views in the same view controller
I have 4 UICollection views on my home page and all 4 are scroll horizontally. From the 4 Collection view First Collection view works like Carousel and scroll Automatically. Other 3 are will not scroll automatically. I am attaching a screen shot for the Home page.



Problem: As UICollectionView 1 autoscroll, all below 3 UICollectionViews also scroll from first cell to second cell. This happens only one time when load the view controller. Once it moves to second cell it will not update next on onwards. As a result very first time UICollectionView 1  update index automatically below 3 UICollectionView get updated and always shows first index cell instead of the 0 index cell.
I am attaching video link to highlight the issue. As soon as I scroll the page and UICollectionView 2,3 and 4 display I have reset them to first index. In the Video actual issue generate at 00:04 seconds.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/cf0198c643744d6f7edc7757510a397d20240513084402/e3dffc
I am attaching the code here. I have create 4 different variable for UICollectionFlowLayout so that it can not effect each other.
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    
    let mainCollectionViewFlowControl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    mainCollectionViewFlowControl.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width - 60, height: 218)
    mainCollectionViewFlowControl.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
    //mainCollectionViewFlowControl.minimumLineSpacing = 8
    //mainCollectionViewFlowControl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20
    mainCollectionViewFlowControl.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left:15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
    self.mainCarouselCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = mainCollectionViewFlowControl
    
    
    let challengesActivityFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    challengesActivityFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 155, height: 186)
    challengesActivityFlowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
    challengesActivityFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    challengesActivityFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    challengesActivityFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    self.challengesActivityCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = challengesActivityFlowLayout
    
    let lifestyleFitnessFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    lifestyleFitnessFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 155, height: 186)
    lifestyleFitnessFlowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
    lifestyleFitnessFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    lifestyleFitnessFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    lifestyleFitnessFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    self.lifestyleFitnessCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = lifestyleFitnessFlowLayout
    
    let communityOtherFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    communityOtherFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 155, height: 186)
    communityOtherFlowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
    communityOtherFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    communityOtherFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    communityOtherFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    self.communityOtherCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = communityOtherFlowLayout
    
}

UICollectionViewDelegate methods
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if collectionView.tag == 1 {
        
        self.challengesActivityPageControl.numberOfPages = challengeActivityArray.count
        
        return self.challengeActivityArray.count
        
    }else if collectionView.tag == 2 {
        
        self.lifestyleFitnessPageControl.numberOfPages = lifestyleFitnessArray.count
        
        return self.lifestyleFitnessArray.count
        
    }else if collectionView.tag == 3 {
        
        self.communityOtherPageControl.numberOfPages = communityOtherArray.count
        
        return self.communityOtherArray.count
        
    }else {
        
        self.pageControllerDots.numberOfPages = self.mainCarouselArray.count
        
        return self.mainCarouselArray.count
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
   if collectionView.tag == 1{
        
        NSLog("Collection View tag::: \(collectionView.tag)")
        
        let carouselCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dashboardCarouselCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! WSCarouselCollectionViewCell
        
        let currentTileObject : [AnyHashable:Any] = challengeActivityArray[indexPath.row]
        
        if currentTileObject["icon"] != nil {
            
            var tempUrlStr: String = currentTileObject["icon"] as! String
            tempUrlStr = tempUrlStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "http:", with: "https:")
            let encodeUrl = tempUrlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
            let tempUrl = URL.init(string: encodeUrl)
            
            carouselCell.tileImageView.sd_setImage(with: tempUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "loadingImage.png"), options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)
            


            NSLog("Swift Challenge Type Carousel Icon ::: \(String(describing: tempUrl))")

            
        }else{
            
            carouselCell.tileImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "loadingImage.png")
        }
        
       // let imageName : String = currentTileObject["icon"] as! String
        
        if let tileName = currentTileObject["tile_name"] as? String {
            
            carouselCell.tileNameLabel.text = tileName
            
        }else{
            
            carouselCell.tileNameLabel.text = ""
        }
        
        if let description = currentTileObject["description"] as? String {
            
            carouselCell.tileDescriptionLabel.text = description
            
        }else{
            
            carouselCell.tileDescriptionLabel.text = ""
        }
       
       carouselCell.tileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
       carouselCell.tileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

       carouselCell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
       carouselCell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
       carouselCell.categoryCarouselParentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
       carouselCell.categoryCarouselParentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
       
        return carouselCell

    }else if collectionView.tag == 2{
        
        NSLog("Collection View tag::: \(collectionView.tag)")
        
        let carouselCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dashboardCarouselCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! WSCarouselCollectionViewCell

        let currentTileObject : [AnyHashable:Any] = lifestyleFitnessArray[indexPath.row]
        
        if currentTileObject["icon"] != nil {
            
            var tempUrlStr: String = currentTileObject["icon"] as! String
            tempUrlStr = tempUrlStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "http:", with: "https:")
            let encodeUrl = tempUrlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
            let tempUrl = URL.init(string: encodeUrl)
            
            carouselCell.tileImageView.sd_setImage(with: tempUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "loadingImage.png"), options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)
            
            NSLog("Swift Lifefitness Type Carousel Icon ::: \(String(describing: tempUrl))")
            
        }else{
            
            carouselCell.tileImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "loadingImage.png")
        }
        
       // let imageName : String = currentTileObject["icon"] as! String
        
        if let tileName = currentTileObject["tile_name"] as? String {
            
            carouselCell.tileNameLabel.text = tileName
            
        }else{
            
            carouselCell.tileNameLabel.text = ""
        }
        
        if let description = currentTileObject["description"] as? String {
            
            carouselCell.tileDescriptionLabel.text = description
            
        }else{
            
            carouselCell.tileDescriptionLabel.text = ""
        }
        
        carouselCell.tileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        carouselCell.tileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
 
        carouselCell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        carouselCell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        carouselCell.categoryCarouselParentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        carouselCell.categoryCarouselParentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        return carouselCell

        
    }else if collectionView.tag == 3{
        
        NSLog("Collection View tag::: \(collectionView.tag)")
        
        let carouselCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dashboardCarouselCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! WSCarouselCollectionViewCell

        let currentTileObject : [AnyHashable:Any] = communityOtherArray[indexPath.row]
        
        if currentTileObject["icon"] != nil {
            
            var tempUrlStr: String = currentTileObject["icon"] as! String
            tempUrlStr = tempUrlStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "http:", with: "https:")
            let encodeUrl = tempUrlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
            let tempUrl = URL.init(string: encodeUrl)
            
            carouselCell.tileImageView.sd_setImage(with: tempUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "loadingImage.png"), options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)
            
            
            NSLog("Swift Community Type Carousel Icon ::: \(String(describing: tempUrl))")
            
        }else{
            
            carouselCell.tileImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "loadingImage.png")
        }
        
       // let imageName : String = currentTileObject["icon"] as! String
        
        if let tileName = currentTileObject["tile_name"] as? String {
            
            carouselCell.tileNameLabel.text = tileName
            
        }else{
            
            carouselCell.tileNameLabel.text = ""
        }
        
        if let description = currentTileObject["description"] as? String {
            
            carouselCell.tileDescriptionLabel.text = description
            
        }else{
            
            carouselCell.tileDescriptionLabel.text = ""
        }
        
        carouselCell.tileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        carouselCell.tileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
 
        carouselCell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        carouselCell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        carouselCell.categoryCarouselParentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        carouselCell.categoryCarouselParentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        
        return carouselCell
        
    }else {
        
        NSLog("Collection View tag::: \(collectionView.tag)")
        
        let carouselCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mainCarouselCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! WSMainCarouselCollectionViewCell

        let subViews = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.subviews
        for subview in subViews{
            
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        let carousel = self.mainCarouselArray[indexPath.row]
        
        
        NSLog("Carousel Dictionary::: \(carousel)")
        NSLog("Carousel Dictionary index::: \(indexPath.row)")
        
        if let tileKey = carousel["tile_key"] as? String {
            
            //if tileKey.count > 0 {
                
                switch tileKey {
                case "tile_average_steps":
                    
                    //Call method which create Activity stats
                    //let monthAvgCarousel = self.manageMonthAverageStepsUI(carousel: carousel, index: indexPath.row)
                    let monthAvgCarousel = carousel["slide_view"] as? UIView
                    
                    if monthAvgCarousel != nil {
                        
                        
                        //monthAvgCarousel?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8)
                        monthAvgCarousel?.frame.origin.x = 4
                        monthAvgCarousel?.frame.origin.y = 4
                        monthAvgCarousel?.frame.size.height = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8
                        monthAvgCarousel?.frame.size.width = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.width - 8
                        carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.addSubview(monthAvgCarousel!)
                    }

                    break
                case "tile_badges":
                    
                    //Call method which create Latest Badges Carousel
                    //let badgeCarousel = self.manageLatestBadgeUI(carousel: carousel, index: indexPath.row)
                    let badgeCarousel = carousel["slide_view"] as? UIView
                    
                    if badgeCarousel != nil {
                        
                        //badgeCarousel?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8)
                        
                        badgeCarousel?.frame.origin.x = 4
                        badgeCarousel?.frame.origin.y = 4
                        badgeCarousel?.frame.size.height = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8
                        badgeCarousel?.frame.size.width = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.width - 8
                        carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.addSubview(badgeCarousel!)
                    }

                    break
                case "tile_friends":
                    
                    //Call method which create Friends UI
                    //let friendsCarousel = self.manageTop3FriendsUI(carousel: carousel, index: indexPath.row)
                    let friendsCarousel = carousel["slide_view"] as? UIView
                    
                    if friendsCarousel != nil {
                        
                        //friendsCarousel?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8)
                        
                        friendsCarousel?.frame.origin.x = 4
                        friendsCarousel?.frame.origin.y = 4
                        friendsCarousel?.frame.size.height = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8
                        friendsCarousel?.frame.size.width = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.width - 8
                        carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.addSubview(friendsCarousel!)
                    }
                    
                    break
                case "tile_dailyjournal":
                    
                    slide9 = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("dailyJournalButtonQuestion", owner: self)?.first as! dailyJournalButtonQuestion
                    
                    //Call method which create Daily journal
                    //let dailyJournalCarousel = self.manageDailyJournalUI(carousel: carousel, index: indexPath.row)
                    let dailyJournalCarousel = carousel["slide_view"] as? UIView
                    
                    if dailyJournalCarousel != nil {
                     
                        //dailyJournalCarousel?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8)
                        
                        dailyJournalCarousel?.frame.origin.x = 4
                        dailyJournalCarousel?.frame.origin.y = 4
                        dailyJournalCarousel?.frame.size.height = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8
                        dailyJournalCarousel?.frame.size.width = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.width - 8
                        carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.addSubview(dailyJournalCarousel!)
                    }
                    
                    break
                case "tile_challenges":
                    
                    //Call method which create challenegs UI
                    //let challengeCarousel = self.manageChallengesUI(carousel: carousel, index: indexPath.row)
                    let challengeCarousel = carousel["slide_view"] as? UIView
                    
                    if challengeCarousel != nil {
                     
                        //challengeCarousel?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8)
                        
                        challengeCarousel?.frame.origin.x = 4
                        challengeCarousel?.frame.origin.y = 4
                        challengeCarousel?.frame.size.height = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8
                        challengeCarousel?.frame.size.width = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.width - 8
                        carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.addSubview(challengeCarousel!)
                    }
                    
                    break
                    
                case "tile_program_information":

                    //Call method which create Progrma Informartion
                    //let progrmaInfoCarousel = self.manageProgramInformartionUI(carousel: carousel, index: indexPath.row)
                    let progrmaInfoCarousel = carousel["slide_view"] as? UIView

                    if progrmaInfoCarousel != nil {
                     
                        //progrmaInfoCarousel?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8)
                        
                        progrmaInfoCarousel?.frame.origin.x = 4
                        progrmaInfoCarousel?.frame.origin.y = 4
                        progrmaInfoCarousel?.frame.size.height = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8
                        progrmaInfoCarousel?.frame.size.width = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.width - 8
                        carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.addSubview(progrmaInfoCarousel!)
                    }

                    break
                    
                case "tile_achivements_steps":

                    //Call method which create Progrma Informartion
                    //let stepsAchievementCarousel = self.manageStepsAchievementsUI(carousel: carousel, index: indexPath.row)
                    let stepsAchievementCarousel = carousel["slide_view"] as? UIView

                    if stepsAchievementCarousel != nil {
                     
                       //stepsAchievementCarousel?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8)
                        
                        stepsAchievementCarousel?.frame.origin.x = 4
                        stepsAchievementCarousel?.frame.origin.y = 4
                        stepsAchievementCarousel?.frame.size.height = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8
                        stepsAchievementCarousel?.frame.size.width = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.width - 8
                        carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.addSubview(stepsAchievementCarousel!)
                    }

                    break
                    
                case "custom_card":

                    //Call method which create Custom Card
                    //let progrmaInfoCarousel = self.manageProgramInformartionUI(carousel: carousel, index: indexPath.row)
                    let customCardCarousel = carousel["slide_view"] as? UIView

                    if customCardCarousel != nil {
                     
                        
                        customCardCarousel?.frame.origin.x = 4
                        customCardCarousel?.frame.origin.y = 4
                        customCardCarousel?.frame.size.height = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.height - 8
                        customCardCarousel?.frame.size.width = carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.frame.size.width - 8
                        carouselCell.mainCarouselParentView.addSubview(customCardCarousel!)
                    }

                    break
                    
                default:
                    break
                }
            
        }
        
        return carouselCell
        
    }
    
    
}

I have start the autoscroll with the help timer. This method call on API response parsing.
func startTimerForMainCarousel(scrollTime: Int ) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        
        self.mainCarouselTimer?.invalidate()
        self.mainCarouselTimer = nil
        self.mainCarouselTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(scrollTime), target: self, selector: #selector(automaticScrollMainCarousel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
   
}

This is automatic scroll method
@objc func automaticScrollMainCarousel() {
    
    if mainCarouselCounter < pageControllerDots.numberOfPages - 1 {
        mainCarouselCounter += 1
    } else {
        mainCarouselCounter = 0
    }
    
    
    pageControllerDots.currentPage = mainCarouselCounter
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: { [weak self] in

        self!.mainCarouselCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self!.mainCarouselCounter, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        self!.pageControllerDots.currentPage = self!.mainCarouselCounter

    })

}

I have spent days to identify the root cause why its move to next cell.

Hi, I tried with part of your code, issue did not reproduce. https://gist.github.com/immanaro2497/80dd9955d3c6b1d081572f4e715cc7a0
